# What is GCC_UNUSED define

Tags: c, ncurses

I've seen this definition GCC_UNUSED used in quite a few places (curses, CDK).
I tried searching for it but I couldn't find anything.
Does anyone know what it means?

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html search for unused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it's a macro definition, something like:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#  define GCC_UNUSED __attribute__((unused))
#else
#  define GCC_UNUSED
#endif
```

The `unused` [attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html), attached to a variable, means that the variable is meant to be possibly unused. GCC will not produce a warning for this variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a GCC macro, it's something the code you're looking at is doing, which is related to GCC.

Most probably a way to avoid "parameter unused"-warnings.